# Why "go version" command fail with an error? No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, macintosh

Below is the environment in Mac:

```
~$
~$
~$ echo $0
-bash
~$
~$
~$
~$
~$
~$ cat /etc/paths.d/go
/usr/local/go/bin
~$
~$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/MYUSER/go/bin
~$
~$
~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/MYUSER/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
~$
~$ uname -a
Darwin XYXYXYXXYX 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Apr 12 20:57:45 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.28.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
~$
~$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
~$
~$
~$
~$ go version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/go: No such file or directory
~$
~$
~$
~$ /usr/local/go/bin/go version
go version go1.16.4 darwin/amd64
~$
~$
```

---

I performed
`rm -rf /usr/local/go` , `rm  /usr/local/bin/go` before installing new version go v1.16 that installs `go` binary in `/usr/local/go/bin`

How to make `go version` command work?

Comment: If it's recognized in your PATH, then it will work. If it isn't, do you get any error messages when attempting to use it?

Comment: @NasirRiley `go version` gives error: `-bash: /usr/local/bin/go: No such file or directory` but `go` binary is in `/usr/local/go/bin` which is part of `$PATH`

Comment: It happens when a dynamic linker cannot be found. Post output of `file $(command -v go)` and `readelf  -a $(command -v go) |& grep 'Requesting pro'`

Comment: Presumably you have a /usr/local/bin/go that symlinks to nowhere.

Comment: @JeffSchaller `~$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/go` gives 
`ls: /usr/local/bin/go: No such file or directory`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `file $(command -v go)` gives `/usr/local/bin/go: cannot open '/usr/local/bin/go' (No such file or directory)`

Comment: @overexchange: can you try running `hash -r` and then `command -v go` again?

Comment: It worked after running `hash -r`.

Comment: Post output of `command -v go` I asked for.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk  `file $(command -v go)` gives 
`/usr/local/go/bin/go: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the snippet you posted in your question it says:

```
~$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

`which` indicates that go binary resides in /usr/local/go/bin directory
(also see [Why not use “which”? What to use
then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then))
but Bash tries to run from it /usr/local/bin directory:

```
~$ go version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/go: No such file or directory
```

This is probably where `go` binary used to reside before you moved or
removed it. In situations like this running `hash -r` may fix the
problem, from `help hash`:

> -r        forget all remembered locations

Comment: yes `go` binary use to reside in `/usr/local/bin`, but I removed before installing new version of go binary that got installed in new location: `/usr/local/go/bin`

Comment: @overexchange Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.